# Shrink ROI in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Trying to shrink ROI (region of interest of an image) and pasting it to the normal size of the rest of the image. It doesn't seem to work though as it is giving me errors. The code I have so far is where x1,x2,y1,y2 are the coordinates of the original roi.

```
resize_roi = cv2.resize(roi,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation =cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #indentation wrong
newimg_res = img.copy()
newimg_res[y1:y2, x1:x2] = resize_roi
cv2.imshow('Resize Rectangle',newimg_res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Maybe have a look here first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Can you add an image, add the errors you get and describe the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

I think in [Vedranh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5013946/vedranh13)'s answer the following line is not correct:

```
newimg_res[(.5 * y1):(.5 * y2), (.5 * x1):(.5 * x2)] = resize_roi;
```

Reason: `0.5*y1<y1`, however, whilst shrinking `x1` and `y1` (upper left corner) moves far from the original location and `x2`, `y2` comes closer. A simple solution is to just add half of the actual width of `ROI` in original cordinate to get `x1` and `y1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is trying to take a subimage, scale it down, and then put it back in the original spot. This is failing because that doesn't make sense. The way to fix this depends on your purpose, but one way would be to change the size of the section you are trying to replace, ex:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('pic.jpe')
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 45, 145, 45, 145
roi = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
resize_roi = cv2.resize(roi,None,fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation =cv2.INTER_CUBIC) #indentation wrong
newimg_res = img.copy()
newimg_res[(.5 * y1):(.5 * y2), (.5 * x1):(.5 * x2)] = resize_roi
cv2.imshow('Resize Rectangle',newimg_res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

While that does run without error, I cannot know if this is what you want without more information about your purpose / expected output